# (Django)How can I compare two attributes of two objects using query sets?

Tags: django, django-queryset

When I have a class employe with the attributes salary(salary = models.PositiveIntegerField()) and boss(boss = models.ForeignKey('employe', null=True)).
How can I find an employe whose salary is higher then the salary of his/her boss using django query-sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/) to get the boss' salary and then compare the fields with something like:

```
from django.db.models import F
Employee.objects.annotate(boss_salary=F("boss__salary"))\
                .filter(salary__gt=F("boss_salary"))
```